# Dual boot on macbook pro 2015 (macOS Sierra and Kali Linux)

Tags: macbook-pro, install, macos, dual-boot

I have a Macbook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015) with macOS Sierra.

For the installation, I have followed this guide: [Installing dual boot Sierra and Kali-Linux](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/257554/installing-dual-boot-sierra-and-kali-linux) but at the end, when I go to part 3 I see only the Mac Hardisk and no other available selection.

Someone have any solution?

Comment: Is there a Kali (or other) image installed on the stick?

Comment: Under Part 2 of those directions it omitted the step of coping the **efi** folder to the _root_ of the Kali Linux partition on the USB drive, so I added it as step 8 under Part 2. Did you copy the **efi** folder to the _root_ of the Kali Linux partition on the USB drive?

Comment: @user3439894 hi, no, I copied in when he was not present in the guide. tomorrow I try again, hoping that this time functions.

Comment: @user3439894 hello, I managed to get it going :); But I noticed that the "persistence" seems to not work; in fact trying (as indicated by the guide) to change the background to see if it keeps on reboot back to being the same default.

Comment: First of all, I'm not the author of the guide you used and only added the obviously missing step in Part 2 and cannot vouch for any of it as I've not tried it. If I was going to try a Kali Live USB with Persistence I'd follow the official documentation, [Making a Kali Bootable USB Drive](http://docs.kali.org/downloading/kali-linux-live-usb-install) & [Kali Linux Live USB Persistence](http://docs.kali.org/downloading/kali-linux-live-usb-persistence) and certainly wouldn't be downloading a binary from some unknown user and implementing it from the guide you linked to in your question!

Comment: @user3439894 ok,  I had already tried to follow the official guide http://docs.kali.org/downloading/kali-linux-live-usb-install   to make a live stick Kali via a PC running Windows (then using the procedure "Creating a Bootable USB Drive on Windows Kali") but then once I tried to use the USB key on my macbook pro, but there was no way to make it work, in addition to having to throw the key into the garbage, since there was not even a way to reformat it (even on another pc with linux could see it).

maybe I will try to follow the procedure with osx.

Answer (score 2):

I used the guide on Kali's official website for me, which is here: https://www.kali.org/docs/installation/dual-boot-kali-with-mac/. I to have a MacBook Pro Retina running OS Sierra, I hope that will help your installation.